Interpretation of costates in Pontryagin's maximum principle in optimal control
In my optimal control class, my professor proposed the following numerical solution approach to solving the necessary conditions for Pontryagin's principle:
He says that, after computing $\lambda(t)$ by integrating backwards in time, $\lambda(t)$ tells you what direction to "nudge" the state trajectory $x(t)$ in to get an improved guess for $u(t)$. Given this intuition, what's the correct interpretation as to what $\lambda(t)$ represents? Does it represent how the cost changes with changes in the trajectory such that it tells us what direction to nudge the trajectory $x(t)$ in to reduce the cost? Also, here is an image showing the notations used:

It is the derivative of the state trajectory.

Is it the derivative of the cost with respect to the state trajectory? i.e. $\frac{\delta J}{\delta \mathbf{x}}$ where $J$ is the cost and $\mathbf{x}$ is the state trajectory

Would you precise the specific equations involved?

I have added it to the post!

Is $\dot x = F(x,u)$ ?

Yes, that's correct.

The described process seems to be an iterative procedure to obtain the minimum/maximum.
It starts with $u_0$ and follows with
$$
\cases{
\dot x_k = F(x_k,u_k),\ \ x_k(0) = x_0\\
\lambda_k(T) = \left(\frac{\partial V(x_k)}{\partial x_k}\right)_{t=T}\\
\text{solve backwards}\ \ \dot\lambda_k = -\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_k}\right)\lambda_k - \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_k}\right)\\
\text{choose}\ u_{k+1}\ \text{from}\ \ \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_k}\right)\lambda_k+\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial u_k}\right) = 0
}
$$
Attached a MATHEMATICA script applied to the case
$$
\cases{
L(x,u) = x^2+u^2\\
V(x(T)) = (x(T)-1)^2\\
F(x,u) = -x-x^3+u\\
x_0 =1.5\\
T = 2\\
u_1 = 2
}
$$
Clear[u1, u2]
T = 2;
x0 = 1.5;
F[x_, u_] := -x - x^3 + u
L[x_, u_] := x^2 + u^2
V[x_] := (x - 1)^2
H[x_, u_, l_] := L[x, u] + l F[x, u]
l'[t] == -D[H[x[t], u[t], l[t]], x[t]];
u1[t_] := 2
gr0 = Plot[u1[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thin}];
GRU = {gr0};
GRX = {};
For[k = 1, k <= 20, k++,
 solx1 = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == F[x1[t], u1[t]], x1[0] == x0}, x1, {t, 0, T}][[1]];
 grx = Plot[Evaluate[x1[t] /. solx1], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thin}];
 AppendTo[GRX, grx];
 l1T = D[V[x1[t]], x1[t]] /. solx1 /. {t -> T};
 ode1 = {l1'[t] == -D[H[x1[t], u1[t], l1[t]], x1[t]], l1[T] == l1T} /. solx1;
 soll1 = NDSolve[ode1, l1, {t, 0, T}][[1]];
 u2 = -1/2 Evaluate[l1[t] /. soll1];
 gru = Plot[u2, {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thin}];
 AppendTo[GRU, gru];
 u1[t_] := u2
 ]

Show[GRX, PlotRange -> All]
Show[GRU, PlotRange -> All]



NOTE
I strongly recommend in the excellent book Applied Optimal Control - Bryson & Ho, the item concerning Neighboring extremal algorithms.

Thank you very much for this. Is V(x) the terminal cost function in this example?

Yes. It is $V(x(T))$.

Thanks. Also, would I be correct in interpreting the costate variable $\lambda(t)$ as the sensitivity of the cost with respect to the state trajectory? At each iteration, I imagine $\lambda(t)$ is basically allowing us to find an improved (lower cost) state trajectory using a gradient descent-like approach as is done in neural networks. Then, solving $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u_k}\lambda_k+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial u_k}=0$ would give us a control input $u_{k+1}$ that would actually result in that improved trajectory.

As the condition guess the next $u_k$ I choose the simpler in the hope it converges. As I cited in the included note at the end of the answer, there are many ways of iterative improvement. This matter is well explained in the chapter 7, Numerical Solution of Optimization Problems, from Applied Optimal Control by Arthur E. Bryson, Jr. and Yu-Chi Ho, possibly can be found at the net.

Thanks I will take a look at the book!

This is more commonly known as an adjoint state, which may help with future literature review. Here is an answer to a related question. I will provide an informal interpretation using multivariable calculus that may aid in interpretation.
Suppose we wish to solve a constrained optimization problem
$$
\min_u J(x,u), \\\text{s.t.}~f(x,u)=0\in V,
$$
where $V$ is some inner product space. For simplicity, assume that $x$ and $u$ also lie in $V$, although that is not necessary. Assume also that for a given $u$, $f(x,u)=0$ admits a unique solution for $x$, so there is a well-defined map $g:u\mapsto x(u)$. Here, $J$ represents the objective and $f$ represents a differential equation written as a nonlinear equation in some function space. We will proceed formally. To perform the minimization, we will compute the derivative of $J$ with respect to the variable and set it equal to zero, keeping in mind that $x$ has an implicit dependence on $u$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d J}{d u} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial J}{\partial u} = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
This is well and good, but we need to compute $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$. We can do this by implicitly differentiating the constraint:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f} {\partial u} &=0\\
\implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} &= -\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial f} {\partial u}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Combining these, we obtain
$$
\frac{d J}{d u} = -\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial f} {\partial u} + \frac{\partial J}{\partial u} = 0.
$$
However, notice the following. To compute this derivative, we need to compute the product of three derivatives in the first term. If we are thinking in terms of finite-dimensional spaces, both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ are matrices that may be large, or infinite when we extend to function spaces. Furthermore, we are required to invert one of these matrices if we want to use this formula as written. This may be inefficient in high dimensions or when approximating infinite-dimensional problems. Notice that this is necessary if we wish to compute these factors "right to left" as written in the equation. This is known as forward mode differentiation and in the context of differential equations, computing $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ in this way is called solving the sensitivity equations.
This seems like a huge pain, but we can alleviate this via noticing that since $J$ is a scalar, $\frac{d J}{d u}$ is necessarily a linear map from $V\to\mathbb{R}$. That is, $\frac{d J}{d u}\in V^*$, the dual space of $V$. Since we are working in an inner product space where there is a natural isomorphism between $V^*$ and $V$, and we can represent any element of the dual space as the adjoint of some element of $V$. We now introduce the adjoint state $\lambda$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lambda &= -\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}\\
\implies \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^*\lambda &= -\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}\right)^*,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\cdot^*$ denotes the adjoint map. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, this would just be a matrix transpose. This is known as the adjoint equation. With this new $\lambda$, our original derivative computation becomes
$$
\frac{d J}{d u} = \lambda\frac{\partial f} {\partial u} + \frac{\partial J}{\partial u}.
$$
Now look at our derivative computation. The steps to compute the derivative are now

Given $u$, compute $x(u)$ by solving $f(x,u)=0$.

Given $x$ (as the matrices are evaluated there), solve the adjoint equation for $\lambda$.

Given $x$ and $u$, compute $\frac{dJ}{du}$.


We have then reduced the burden of explicitly computing and inverting large Jacobian operators with solving two equations in sequence then combining the solutions to obtain the derivative to be used in, e.g., gradient descent. Now if you look back at how $\lambda$ was defined, notice that it represents the product of the leftmost terms in the original product, so we are now computing derivatives "left to right," known as reverse-mode differentiation. From this, we can see that, formally, the adjoint state is nothing more than a formal representation of how the sensitivity of the objective due to the state ($-\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}$) propogates through the solution operator obtained by inverting the constraint $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}^{-1}$). I would recommend you investigate the linked post and answer if you want a better interpretation specifically in the time-dependent setting.

How is different from the usual Lagrangian multiplier?

It is the usual LM. Notice that the adjoint equation looks similar to $\lambda \nabla f = \nabla J$. The difference is that now the left gradient is a linear operator and the right gradient is a dual vector so we can reformulate it as a linear equation.

Here is a presentation of this method explicitly using Lagrange multipliers
